# Location of `object.__init__`

Tags: python, cpython

Where is `object.__init__` located in the cpython repository?
I searched for `__init__` in `Objects/object.c`, but it gives no results.

It appears that all the immutable data types use `object.__init__`, so I would like to know the implementation of it.

Comment: Are you aware of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) for the C API?

Comment: thanks for the link, will check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Objects/object.c` is where (most of) the [object protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) is implemented, not where `object` is implemented.

`object` is implemented along with `type` in `Objects/typeobject.c`, and its `__init__` method is [`object_init`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L4423) in that file.

(Note that the very similar-sounding [`PyObject_Init`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/allocation.html#c.PyObject_Init) function is actually completely unrelated to `object.__init__`. `PyObject_Init` is a generic helper function that performs type pointer and refcount initialization for a newly-allocated object struct.)